# Google Sites as Front End and App Engine as Back End

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, servlets, google-sites

I'm trying to have a Google Site with JQuery UI as Front End and use a Servlet with access to a Database deployed on Google App Engine. I know about the cross-origin JS problem but i didn't think it would apply in this case as both are essentially hosted by google and i thought i saw someone doing it this way already.

After a simple test though:

- Deployed the example project created when creating a dynamic web
  project in eclipse to App engine containing a servlet which returns
  Hello, World on Http GET.
- added this JS to a button click in my Google Site safe html bypass frame:

  $.get(
  "http://myapplicationID.appspot.com/mycustomserver",
  function(data) {
     alert('page content: ' + data);
  });

What i get when then clicking the button is Mixed content, linking to this page (i'm using Firefox for testing): [Firefox Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Sicherheit/MixedContent)

Is there anything i can do to avoid this problem or is the structure i'm aiming for just not possible?

Edit:
"Updated" question in my last comment.

I also found a dirty workaround which i'm actually avoiding right now:
Put the Html, JS, .... in a Html file and deploy it with your app engine app. In Google Sites you can then embed this html file/web page using the iframe gadget.

Comment: Where did you put the code, htmlbox or page html? I dont think you can use javascript (or jquery) on either.

Comment: I put it into a "safe HTML bypass" widget which works (at least in Firefox)

Comment: The safe HTML bypass gadget didn't quite work so well when opened in Chrome but this trick [link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-add-javascript-or-custom-contents-to-google-sites-with-gadget/) works for displaying custom html and javascript even when using a JS Framework hosted by Google (in my case JQuery UI).
...but when executing the GET it logs the obvious Cross-domain JS Request error.

Is there a way to execute Ajax against a App Engine Application from   Google Sites without running into Cross-Domain?

Comment: You can use Gadget Iframe with APP engine. so you need tutotial ,You want to know how to integrate An app engine's application on Google sites

Comment: Not really. I already managed to integrate a static html which is part of my deployed app engine application using the Iframe and it works like it should but i'm trying to avoid this way.
I would like to my GAE App only as a Data Backend consisting out of an HttpServlet handling Http Post and Get coming from the Google site's Javascript.
My problem being that right now i'm facing the Cross-Domain Request problem. So again: I'm just trying to send a GET request from Google site to App engine.

Comment: have you tried loading as if it were a library, using jsonp?

Comment: Not until now. I actually just heard that it was even a thing.
So i searched round the web and made a quick test but i seem to have made something wrong:  
JavaScript:  
`$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: "myurl",
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'callback',
jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert(data);
}
});});});`  
Java:  
in my doGet i return Hello, World with some headers,  
in my doPost i return in this case: jsonPCallback({test = 'test'})  
  
What i get in the console output is:  
ReferenceError: Hello is not defined  
So it jumps into doGet???